# wcf XMLserialization inconsistency with DateTime with GMT offset

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization

I am using a third party service that serializes an objects containing datetimes. Some DateTime properties in some classes serialize to a string with an offset like:

2012-03-22T15:31:18 **-05:00**

Some DateTime properties in some classes serialize to a string without an offset like:

2012-03-24T00:00:00

I believe that the service is expecting an datetime offset.
Is there any way I can force the classes to serialize a datetime offset ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that some DateTime serial with a GMT offset and some do not has to do with the  **Kind property** of DateTime

DateTimes create with a DateTime.Now() set their Kind property as DateTimeKind.Local
DateTimes create with a DateTime.Parse() set their Kind property as DateTimeKind.Unspecified

The function ToString("o") can be used to serialize out to GMT format. The Kind of unspecified does not know the offset so it is skipped.

unspecified Kind: 2012-03-24T00:00:00
local Kind:       2012-03-22T15:31:18 -05:00

There is a function called SpecifyKind but that only works if the kind is **NOT** set to unspecified.

The solution is to create the DateTime with the following constructor:
DateTime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute,Second, DateTimeKind.Local);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t882fzc6.aspx

I created a short extension method for this:

```
    public static DateTime SpecifyKindLocal(this DateTime datetime)
    {
        return new DateTime(datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day, datetime.Hour, datetime.Minute, datetime.Second, DateTimeKind.Local);
    }
```

I hope it helps someone else